# Error in Login Activity In Android

Tags: android, if-statement

I am trying to display an error message when the username and password do not match in my application. On button click with the proper name and password it is working perfectly and display the message login successful but else condition is not working.
Where am I wrong?

**Login.java**

```
private class SigIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
          private final Context _context;  

          public SigIn(Context context){
                _context = context;

            }
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @SuppressLint("WorldReadableFiles")
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
        {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try 
                {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait signing in...");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            pDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                    euid = uedit.getText().toString();
                    epass = pedit.getText().toString();

                    euid.replace("" ,"%20");
                    epass.replace("" ,"%20");
                    job.put("status_key","2");
                    job.put("method", "login");
                    job.put("email", euid);
                    job.put("password",epass );



                /*
                    System.out.print("latitude is "+latitude);
                    job.put("latitude",latitude);
                    job.put("longitude",longitude);*/

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");

                    httppost.setEntity(se);

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                      System.out.println("response "+data);

                      JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                    JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
                    Log.d("Array", jArray.toString(4));
                    JSONObject adv= jo.getJSONObject("advertisement_count");  
                    advertisement_count=adv.getString("count(*)");
                    System.out.print("advertisemnet"+advertisement_count);              
                    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                        JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
                                msname = jsob.getString("Surname");
                                mun = jsob.getString("unit_no");
                                mstreet = jsob.getString("street_name");
                                msuburb = jsob.getString("Suburb");
                                mstate = jsob.getString("State");
                                mpassword = jsob.getString("password");
                                mpostcode = jsob.getString("post_code");
                                mlicense = jsob.getString("driving_lic");
                                mid = jsob.getString("authority_id");
                                mmobile = jsob.getString("mobile_no");
                                memail = jsob.getString("Email");
                                login_token=jsob.getString("login_token");
                                mimagelicense=jsob.getString("license_pic");
                                mauthcard=jsob.getString("audit_card_pic");
                                mpic=jsob.getString("face_pic");
 } catch (JSONException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
}
pref=getSharedPreferences("Driver", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=pref.edit();

                    edit.putString("mfname", mfname);
                    edit.putString("msname", msname);
                    edit.putString("mun", mun);
                    edit.putString("mstreet", mstreet);
                    edit.putString("msuburb", msuburb);
                    edit.putString("mpassword", mpassword);
                    edit.putString("mpostcode", mpostcode);
                    edit.putString("mlicense", mlicense);
                    edit.putString("mid", mid);
                    edit.putString("mmobile", mmobile);
                    edit.putString("memail", memail);
                    edit.putString("login_token", login_token);
                    edit.putString("mimagelicense", mimagelicense);
                    edit.putString("mauthcard", mauthcard);
                    edit.putString("mpic", mpic);
                    edit.putString("advertisement_count", advertisement_count);
                    edit.commit();

    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                        {
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Login !!!");
                            //alert.setTitle("Login unsuccessfull !");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                            //alert.setMessage("Username and password does not match.");
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) 
                                {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                    /*Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                           startActivity(tabint);*/
                                    Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                       startActivity(tabint);
                            }
                            });
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        else if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("300"))
                        {
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Login!!!");
                            alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) 
                                {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                    //Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                         //  startActivity(tabint);
                            }
                            });
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                            alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",

                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                            {
                                public void run() 
                                {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();

                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return params;
            }
```

After login with different username and password it will give me error in log cat like:

```
06-10 03:41:20.550: W/System.err(32253): org.json.JSONException: No value for driver_details
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:263)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-10 03:41:20.570: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-10 03:41:20.570: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Comment: can you send me the JSonObject as String please :D

Comment: Yeah pls post it here in the answer.

Comment: I have add the code as you tell now please solve this problem...

Comment: The only difference I see is you call pDialog.dismiss(); before alert.show(); in the error case, did you try to move it to the button onClick handler as for the other cases ?